# addition of rows and grand total in 2d lists python

Tags: python

I am supposed to add up all the numbers in each row an output that number, and output the grand total of all rows, and i'm pretty lost, can someone point me in the right direction? 
This is the list and system code to work from:

```
import sys
numbers= sys.argv[1:]
for i in range(0,len(numbers)): 
  numbers[i]= numbers[i].split(',')
```

This is my code:

```
for i in range (0,row):
total = total + i
print (total)
```

Comment: You might want to show the input. And you're not showing the full code since you are saying `for i in range(0, row):` with an undefined `row` variable.

Comment: i don't know how many rows there are that's one thing that makes this so hard to figure out.

Comment: I must insist, show us the input you are receiving. There **must** be a fixed format for the data.

Comment: The list and system code shown in the question is all i have to work from, if there is a fixed format i don't have it.

Comment: without having any input I don't see what it is you are trying to achieve. This "numbers" will generally not be a 2d list so "adding up numbers in each row" wouldnt really apply..

Answer (score 3):

Since you only want help being *directed* and not have a full answer, here is what you should do :

- Identify your data. Find similiarities, ways to break the data down to units you can work on. In `"1,2,3,4,5"`, you see there's a `,` that separates your numbers. Identifying this helps you know what to do next : if you want to isolate each number, you can **split** your string using the common character `,` you have found to get a **list** of numbers, written as strings.
- Know where you're going. You want to **sum** all the numbers in an **array** ? Be sure this is actually doable. You can't sum numbers which are not considered as *numbers* by your machine, right ? So tell your machine they are numbers by **casting** such as if `"1"` is a **string**, you could do `int("1")` to transform your string into a number. Note that you can't cast something like `"1,"` into a number because `,` can't be a number.

Now, what you should do as pseudo-code, reading your post. You have a **list** of **list** containing numbers. You want to sum each sublist, and show the grand total sum.

```
grand_total = 0
# This will iterate through your list of list.
for row in numbers:
    # Each "row" is a list of numbers.
    row_sum = make_the_sum_of_the_current_list_here

    # Want to print it ? Print it !
    print row_sum

    # But don't forget to add this value to the grand_total.
    grand_total = grand_total + row_sum

# Print the sum of all sums.
print grand_total
```